# Don't know how to merge two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new in SQL queries. I have a problem with the query.

I have table books:

```
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
| id | title | author | publisher |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Book1 |      1 |         1 |
|  2 | Book2 |      1 |         2 |
|  3 | Book3 |      2 |         1 |
|  4 | Book4 |      2 |         2 |
|  5 | Book5 |      2 |         3 |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
```

And I'm have another table, which contains copies of books with given book_id.

```
+----+---------+
| id | book_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       1 |
|  2 |       1 |
|  3 |       1 |
|  4 |       2 |
|  5 |       2 |
|  6 |       3 |
|  7 |       4 |
|  8 |       4 |
|  9 |       5 |
+----+---------+
```

All I need is to merge these two tables into one to have table sorted by amount of book copies.

I found solution to get table sorted by amount of book copies:

```
select book_copies.book_id, count(*) total_count 
from book_copies 
group by book_id 
having count(*) > 0 
order by count(*) desc;

+---------+-------------+
| book_id | total_count |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           3 |
|       2 |           2 |
|       4 |           2 |
|       3 |           1 |
|       5 |           1 |
+---------+-------------+
```

Now I don't know how to merge them.

I've tried like this:

```
select books.title from books 
left join 
(select book_copies.book_id, count(*) total_count 
from book_copies 
group by book_id 
having count(*) > 0 
order by count(*) desc) 
as total_table on books.id = total_table.book_id;
```

But all I get was this:

```
+-------+
| title |
+-------+
| Book1 |
| Book2 |
| Book3 |
| Book4 |
| Book5 |
+-------+
```

Could you help me please?

**EDIT:** by merging I meant smth like this:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+-----+
| title | author | publisher | tot |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----+
| Book1 |      1 |         1 |   3 |
| Book2 |      1 |         2 |   2 |
| Book4 |      2 |         2 |   2 |
| Book3 |      2 |         1 |   1 |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----+
```

### Many thanks to @Marco for the answer!

Dmitriy

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "merge" ? The question, to me, isn't clear.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the desired output?

Comment: seems like you have pretty much done. Can you tell what exactly merging means by posting a sample output

Comment: are you just forgetting to add subquery columns? select books.title **,total_table.total_count** from books....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try:

```
SELECT b.title, b.author, b.publisher, COUNT(bc.book_id) AS tot
FROM books b LEFT JOIN  book_copies bc
    ON b.id = bc.book_id
GROUP BY b.id
```

**EDITED:**
If you want sort, you can try

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT b.title, b.author, b.publisher, COUNT(bc.book_id) AS tot
    FROM books b LEFT JOIN  book_copies bc
        ON b.id = bc.book_id
    GROUP BY b.id) g
ORDER BY g.tot DESC
```

Comment: Close, but `COUNT(*)` will return 1 even if there is no record found in book_copies. Change it to `COUNT(bc.book_id)`.

Comment: @GolezTrol: yes, I think it should work (I cannot test it now), but till 1min ago I had -2 for my answer :) Never mind, I try my best... that's enough

Comment: I see the original question want the result sorted by copies as well. Maybe that's the issue. I think it should be possible to `ORDER BY count(bc.book_id) DESC` as well, so that should be solved just as easily.

Comment: @GolezTrol: uh, I missed it, you're right. My edited answer should face that problem. Thanks